# Max image size on Android device

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, textures, cocos2d-android

I am porting an existing game from iOS to Android, and would like to know if there's a size limit for PNG images? On old iOS devices, the texture atlas size cannot exceed 1024 x 1024 pixels. Does a similar limitation exist for Android devices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the only limit is the device's RAM being used.

Answer (score 5):

In android you can use atlas bigger, but I recommend to you use only sizes based on 2; 1024 x 1024; 2048 x 2048, etc. Sometimes Android fail when use custom sizes.